# How can I make my hexagon grid fit all devices?

Tags: html, css

I am currently designing the home page of my website and I want to make a responsive website with 5 hexagon-shaped images, 3 on top, 2 on the bottom. So I created a container with a width of 90% and a height of 65vh it responds nicely to different screen sizes. I then made my 5 hexagons and set up the dimensions for my images, it looks fine on the mobile devices in chrome developer tools but you can see my hexagons appear bigger on ipad sized devices and becomes too big of an issue to ignore with laptops and bigger. Thats not the issue as I can change that by using @media queries. 
I then decided to check all the mobile devices dimensions before I do @media and it works great for devices whose height is greater than or equel to the device width but my bottom 2 hexagons leave the screen if my device width is greater than the height. I have tried different approaches and I'm encountering the same issue. Its like they adjust to the change in screen width but not height.

Comment: Could you paste the overall code of what you were doing till now?

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I found out the problem was I needed to design the website for landscape mode because obviously asmaller height and larger width is landscape, Ill throw up the media query in case anyone stumbles on it:

`@media (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape)`